Running Cucumber features parallelly in threads with each thread having individual isolated DB
In my project there are 1000s of features for Integration test which took a lot of time to run sequentially. I'm trying to run it parallelly.
The issue I face is that, a group of feature files use same base class which is using the same db.
When running in parallel, these features will try to modify the same db(postgresdb), which will cause the some of the db queries to fail which will then lead to test failures. My tests will run fine if I use a isolated db for each thread. Is there a way i can do that?
Im using
@ConfigurationParameter(key = Constants.PARALLEL_EXECUTION_ENABLED_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "true")

to achieve parallel execution and
@ConfigurationParameter(key = Constants.EXECUTION_MODE_FEATURE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "same_thread") since i want all my scenarios to run in the same thread and
@ConfigurationParameter(key = Constants.PARALLEL_CONFIG_FIXED_PARALLELISM_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "4") since I want to limit my parallely executing features to a fixed number
I want 4 db containers to be initiated when the test starts running and each db should be assigned to a particular thread till the test ends
(Currently, Im using single datasource which is defined in the application-test.yml)

I don't think that what you're trying to do will work. Instead, try to design the tests so they don't interact with each other.

Thanks for the reply. I was trying to do this with minimal code change. Will work on isolating tests
